# Can I hide a transformer in a metal box in my cabinet?

Tags: electrical

I put LED lights under my cabinets.  I ran the wires into the cabinet where I put a 4 in metal box. Was going to put the small unit and wires inside the box but noticed the transformer gets real warm. Maybe I bought the wrong product?  It's  a 60W 12v by lightech.

Comment: What is the model number of the transformer?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find on the model you cited [here](http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Lightech-60-Watt-12-Volt-Electronic-Transformer-GELT60A12012DIY/203586278).
It is a sealed unit meant for halogen fixtures so it would normally be mounted inside a light fixture or other enclosure anyway.

Therefore, I don't think you need to worry about heat. But if you are OCD you could epoxy it to the metal cover of the 4" box and the cover would act as a heat sink and radiate away some of the heat.

Good luck!

Comment: That is an AC "transformer" (output leads are the same color) and it may work oddly with 12V LEDs, which generally want DC.  At best they will make the LEDs shimmer, so if you turn your head, they will leave glittery little tracks across your eyes, like some car taillights do.  Try a DC power supply instead.